# Fill the combo ExtJS by the custom data

Tags: arrays, extjs, datareader

I have `Combo` ExtJS, that should be filled by the data from Spring MVC - like this:

```
    var LongRecord = Ext.data.Record.create([
        {name: 'id', mapping: 'id'}
    ]);

     var comboStore = new MyDataStore.data.Store({
        proxy: new MyDataStore.data.DwrProxy({
            invoker: function(params, arg, cb) {
                // data from server
                AssetScreener.getEntityOwnerIds(cb);
                console.log("invoker has been called");     
            }
        }),

        reader: new Ext.data.ArrayReader({}, LongRecord),
        listeners: {
               'load': function(s, recs) { 
                alert("!");

            }
         }
    });
```

Combo code:

```
new Ext.form.ComboBox({
  store:  comboStore,
  typeAhead: true,
  triggerAction: 'all',
  editable: false,
  width: 100,
  displayField: 'id',
  valueField: 'id'
});
```

Problem is that data, that I'm getting from server, looks like this

```
'5','0',["1","8","133"]
```

I need to slice the array `["1","8","133"]` and show this in combo (change backend java-code is unwishable way).

In combo after this code is executed I see the three empty items. Need hints, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the load event, you'll get the `["1","8","133"]` from the `recs` parameter after slicing. Use `store.loadData()` to replace the current store records with the correct ones.

You can create a model out of the array to feed the store like so:

```
var i, item, feed = [];
for(i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
   item = array[i];
   feed.push(Ext.create('com.your.Model', {
       id : item
   }));
}
store.loadData(feed);
```

Comment: Just like this:

    store.loadData(["1","8","133"])    ?

In the "load"'s callback ?

Comment: In the load event. You could do it in the callback too but for that you'll need to disable autoLoad and fire a manual `store.load()`. I think it should directly accept the array, otherwise you could always create a `model` out of the data. I'll update the answer with how to do that.

Comment: Did the direct load work or did you need to convert it into a model first? Please let us know.

Comment: I used the converting into model as you recommend.

Comment: please, hint me else one moment. Your code is workink from console: but when I try to set obtained array to combo, I see that this code is not execuretm, becouse of 'store:feed' doesn't use my store, which has your code. How to fix it ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm unable to understand your question. What is `store:feed`? When are you trying to set the array? In the load event of the store?